# Nested quantifiers: Please give me a solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

How can I express this proposition using predicates and quantifiers?

*There are at least two paths connecting every two distinct endpoints on the network*

Comment: Thanks for your reply Oscar. But how I can express this using predicates and quantifiers?#

Comment: For all $v$ in the set of notes and all $w$ in the set of nodes, there exists positive integers $n$ and $m$ such that there exists a tuples $p=(p_1,p_2,...,p_n)$ and $q=(q_1,q_2,...,q_m)$ of nodes, such that $p_1=q_1=v$ and $q_m=p_n=w$ and for all $i=1,2,...,n-1$ we have that $(p_i,p_{i+1})$ is an edge of the network and for all $j=1,2,...,m-1$ we have that $(q_j,q_{j+1})$ is an edge of the network, and either $n\neq m$ or ( $m=n$ and there exists $k\leq n$ such that $p_k\neq q_k$).

Comment: "For all" and "exists" are the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$. Replace each one by one.

Comment: Could this be a solution: $$\forall e1\forall e2((e1\ \neq\ e2)\ \rightarrow\ \exists p1\exists p2\ [C(p1,e1)\ \land\ C(p2,e2)\ \land\ \ (p1\ \neq\ p2]))$$ where $C(p , e)$ = path $p$ is connected to endpoint $e$…….?

Comment: Yes, but with something like $C(p,e,f)$ meaning $p$ is a path that connects the nodes $e$ and $f$. Then $C(p_1,e_1,e_2)$ and $C(p_2,e_1,e_2)$ are what we use in the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two paths connecting every two distinct endpoints on the network.

For all $x,y$ (($x$ endpoint on network and $y$ endpoint on network and not-($x = y$)) implies exists $p,q$ with ($p$ path and $q$ path and not-($p = q$) and ($p$ connects $x$ and $y$) and ($q$ connects $x$ and $y$))).

Comment: Thank you William Elliot. What if I assume the domain of endpoints x and y are all endpoints connected to that network? Can I right then $$\forall e1\forall e2((e1\ \neq\ e2)\ \rightarrow\ \exists p1\exists p2\ [C(p1,e1)\ \land\ C(p2,e2)\ \land\ \ (p1\ \neq\ p2]))$$ where $C(p , e)$ = path $p$ is connected to endpoint $e$?(e1 for x and e2 for y)

Comment: You can not use an implicit domain here; you must explicitly identify *which* entities are to belong to *which* category.  Also you must specify that *each* path connects *both* end points.